# Is it always true that $X$ embeds into $X^{''}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Let $x \in X$. Than $x$ defines a linear operator $J_x$ on the dual $X^{'}$. But it's always true that this operator induced by $x$ is continuous with respect to the strong topology of $X^{'}$? Clearly it's true for normed vector spaces. I don't know how to treat the general case.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: If your space is a general topological vector space then there may be no continuous linear functionals other than $0$! Also there is no such thing as strong topology on the dual.

Comment: The strong topology $\beta(X',X)$ is the topology of uniform convergence on the bounded subsets of $X$. As singletons are bounded, every evaluation $J_x: f\mapsto f(x)$ is continuous on $(X',\beta(X',X))$.

Comment: A nice example of $X'=0$ as mentioned by @KaviRamaMurthy is $L^p[0,1]$ with $0 < p < 1$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for the information.

Comment: The fact is that $X^{'}$ is not a general vector space at this point. $X^{'}$ is locally convex with that topology! So we know that in the case of normed spaces every point of $X$ induces a continuous lineare functional on the dual. My question is: does this remain true if $X$ is not normed?

Comment: Ok @Jochen, every singleton is bounded, it was easier than I thought.